# spring mvc download file not showing extension

Tags: spring-mvc, download

I'm trying to let customers download sample excel file. Here is my code:

```
String path = UploadController.class.getResource("/com/medify/data/" + file).getFile();

    response.setContentType("application/force-download");
    response.setContentType("application/excel");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file); 

    try{
        File fi = new File(path);
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fi));
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
        response.flushBuffer();

        return null;
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        return null;
    }
```

The problem is the downloaded file never have file extension. The file is **sample-doctor-uploads.xls** and it exists in **com/medify/data** package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use proper content type. If your file has .xls extention you need to use -

```
response.contentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
```

and use the full file name with extention like-

```
response.setHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=fileNamewithExtention"
```